# How to ask an university for application selection result before accepting an offer from another university?

Tags: masters, application, graduate-admissions

I have an offer from one university and still awaiting results from others.

How to approach other universities and ask them about my application status so that I receive my selection / rejection before the deadline of accepting the offer? Is it rude to inform the universities that I have an offer from another university and will be accepting if the results are not announced before the deadline?

All the universities are in the same region.

Comment: **Just ask.**  No, it's not rude.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like everybody else is saying: **Just Ask.**

And do it sooner rather later. Telling a university that you have an offer already will signal that other schools' further along in the process think you're great.

And anyway, you have absolutely nothing to lose by asking. If they want you, they're not going to think it's annoying and will be afraid that will lose you to your other offer. If they don't want you, asking can't hurt. If they are on the fence, a signal that you're admittable will only help.

Answer (score 9):

A related, but not truly duplicate, [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9057/929)

Just ask. Tell them you have been accept at X, but Y is your first choice. The admissions committee does not need much explanation since it happens all the time. Asking to speed up the process will not hurt your chances. They may not be able to speed anything up, but if they do/don't, they will not hold it against you.